# Unidentified address in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Many times, when I copy&paste an email address into the "To" field in a Gmail message, it refuses to send the email, saying that “the address has not been identified”. This is very frustrating. Is there any solution other than just manually typing the address?

Comment: Make sure you don’t paste empty spaces as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such an error message typically looks like the following image and might be due to the fact that the clipboard contains some special characters in addition to the email address that you are trying to copy, which Gmail doesn't display but complains about. Copy your clipboard to some ASCII editor like notepad.exe on Windows or the address bar in Google Chrome to see the special characters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The characters are not visible in notepad, but, they are visible using this link: http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Comment: Cool website, thanks! I hope Gmail will fix it, but they are more into (bad) UI design right now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to delete last hidden character in email-address. Thus press key 'End' and then press key 'Backspace'.